# Google Go datastore interfaces

Tags: postgresql, go, thrift, hypertable

What are your thoughts on [go-pgsql](http://github.com/lxn/go-pgsql) and [thrift4go](https://github.com/pomack/thrift4go)?

I'd like to use Go with either Postgres or Hypertable for a project, but I'm curious as to how mature and complete these interfaces are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have specific experience with `go-psql`, but since there's no answer I'll write my thoughts.

There are issues with the current implementation, which might bite you (e.g. time resolution lower than seconds is ignored. What happens if you update a single field, but your `ORM` decides to include a `time` field within the query?).

Other problem that I see is, there's no promise this project will be maintained as long as you wish.

Another approach is to build a very simple binding to the `postgres` C interface, and just use it. In that case, the abstraction is not very helpful, but definitely not leaky. And it might be enough.

That's what Russ Cox (from the core Go (golang) team) ended up doing [for sqlite](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/msg/15a3f2e3c7ae3a85).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I ended up going with Hypertable, and it seems like Thrift will work reasonably well.